# TextBox Values on ReportViewer

Tags: wpf, vb.net, reportviewer

i would like to know if it is possible when creating a rdlc report use values from TextBoxes with a value already, for exemple i have a textbox bound to an expression:

```
=Fields!PrijsPerStuk.Value * 100 \ Fields!KortingPercentage.Value
```

Now thats textbox1 for exemple and on TextBox2 i would like to show something like:

```
=Fileds!PrijsPerStuk.Value - TextBox1.Value
```

Im not able to do like that, but is there anyway to make it possible? or do i need to change my Query in a way that i get a field with the value of textbox1?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have input parameters for you report that's the way to pass data from your application to it. Update parameters (I guess from your WPF UI) and refresh the report.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure, but try with this:
=Fileds!PrijsPerStuk.Value - ReportItems!TextBox1.Value

We use ReportItems to access other controls in the same section of a report

Answer (score 0):

```
=Fileds!PrijsPerStuk.Value - ReportItems("TextBox1").Value
```